# Using jquery instead of CURL and authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, authentication

I am trying to get item list as XML from Handshake App. They gave some rest APIs. Handshake API help is [here](https://help.handshake.com/customer/portal/articles/1028684-authentication).

I have encountered authentication problem.

They say use curl

```
$ curl -u 2c493d74:X https://app.handshake.com/api/v2/orders
```

I use AJAX to get data from the server but keep getting `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://app.handshake.com/api/v2/items.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
        },
        success: function (xml) {
            console.log(xml);
        }
    });
});
```

I am not sure if I should use `username`+`password` or `API key`+`x`. Neither working.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

> ```
> btoa("username:password")
> ```

This uses `username` and `password` as the strings they are. If this is the same as in your code, change this.

Otherwise, you actually need to use your `apiKey` and `password`.

From the documentation:

> the Handshake API requires that you use HTTP basic authentication to pass your API key with each request. You should pass the API key as the username along with 'X' as the password.

Your code should look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var apiKey = getApiKey(); // these are just placeholders
    var password = getPassword(); //for however you store your api key
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://app.handshake.com/api/v2/items.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa([apiKey, password].join(":"))); 
        },
```